# Unable to recieve Cloud Notifiations in Android Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have this Cloud Function working correctly in iOS, which sends a Firebase Push Notification when a new message is created:

```
export const sendChatNotification = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chats/{chatId}').onCreate(async (snap, ctx) => {

    const token = snap.get('sendToDeviceToken'); 
    const sender = snap.get('fullSenderName'); 
    const body = snap.get('message'); 


    var tokens  = [];

    tokens.push(token);

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: sender,
                body: body,
            },
            android: {
                notification: {
                    channelId: "roofdeck_default",
                    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                    title: sender,
                    body: body,
                }
            },
            apns: {
                headers: {
                    "apns-push-type": "alert"
                },
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        category: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
                    }
                },
            },
            data: {
                postID: snap.id,
                type: "POST_TAG",
            },
            tokens: tokens
        }
    
        if (tokens.length > 0) {
            await fcm.sendMulticast(payload);
        }
});
```

I thought the problem was the Android Notification Channel but today I was able to generate it by following this tutorial: [Android Push Notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7aIZ3aEi2w)

I have added to my **AndroidManifes.xml** the lines:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="roofdeck_default"/>
```

I also created the Local Notification Service (as using the Flutter Local Notifications for Foreground mode).

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
    );

    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
    print('Initialized Notifications');
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000;

      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "roofdeck_default",
          "roofdeck_channel",
          channelDescription: "RoofDeck Main Channel",
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
      );

      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id.toInt(),
        message.notification.title,
        message.notification.body,
        notificationDetails,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Channel Error: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Also initialize the Local Notifications on the Init of the app in Main:

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now I tried doing a test from the Firebase Cloud Messaging Control using the Android Channel I have, and it is working perfectly like that, however on the Automatic Cloud Function doesn't work in Android.

Any Idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Do you create `AndroidNotificationChannel` and use `resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation` of local notifications plugin to setup this channel?

Comment: Hey Peter just the things you see is all I have do you have a Tutorial or something for that? I thought just in initialization should be enough

Comment: [Check out this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#foreground-notifications), I followed this guide and it worked for me.

Comment: Did that I added this lines on my Main file: 

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  description:
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.max,
  playSound: true,
);


final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Comment: Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('A bg message just showed up: ${message.messageId}');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

Comment: await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Comment: And this on Message:

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // if (message.notification != null) {
      //   print(message.notification.body);
      //   print(message.notification.title);
      // }
      // LocalNotificationService.display(message);

      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,

Comment: notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            color: Colors.blue,
            playSound: true,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
          )),
        );
      }
    });

Comment: Still not receiving any notifications, now not even the ones from the cloud Messaging platform

Comment: But you channel name is `roofdeck_default` and not `high_importance_channel`...

Comment: I changed the name in this to apply the same code as in the example

Comment: I changed the Channel name to be roofdeck_default, and I put the metadata under the line FlutterEmbedding, after that I was able to receive from the Firebase Cloud Messanging Panel, but still is not working the Cloud Functions, I believe that the Cloud Funtion is having the Issue, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas.

Comment: No Problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey just to let you know, the issue seems to be that the Payload is working differently from what I had this Android section:

android: {
notification: {
channelId: "roofdeck_default",
click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
title: sender,
body: body,
}
},

Instead of channelId to channel_id.

Kind regards